# How do I write a JavaScript program for the question given below

Tags: javascript

Write a function that takes three (str, c, n) arguments. Start with the end of 'str'. Insert character c after every n characters?

```js
function three(str, c, n){
  for(let i =0; i<str.length; i= i+n){
   str.slice(i, i+n);
   str = str + c;
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(three("apple", "c", 2));
```

I think, I am using wrong method.

Comment: `str.slice(i, i+n);` does not do anything. [`slice`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) _returns_ a new string, but you discard this return value here.

Comment: I see that you are new to Stackoverflow so I wanted to mention a few things.
Try to have a more clear title for your questions that can help others with a similar question.
The more data you provide the easier for others to give answer.
Vote up the questions and answers that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Start with the end of 'str'. Insert character c after every n characters?

I assumed this means the string needs to end with `c` after the change. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If that's the case [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can help here:

```js
function three (str, c, n) {
  return str.split('').reverse().map((currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    if (currentIndex % n === 0) {
      return currentValue + c
    } else {
      return currentValue
    }
  }).reverse().join('')
}

console.log(three("apple", "c", 2));
```

Comment: You're right. This was the required output. Actually, This question was asked in an interview. Thanks a lot for your help. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```js
function three(str, c, n){
  // split the string into an array
  let letters = str.split('');
  // copy to another array that will be the end result to avoid modifying original array
  let result = [...letters];
  // When we add to the array, it shift the next one and so on, so we need to account for that
  let shift = 0;

  // we go over each letter
  letters.forEach((letter,index) => {
      // if we are at the desired location
      if(index > 0 && index % n == 0) {
          // we add our letter at that location
          result.splice(index+shift, 0, c);
          // we increase shift by 1
          shift++;
      }
  })

  // we return the result by joining the array to obtain a string
  return result.join('');
}
console.log(three("apple", "c", 2));//apcplce
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I wish I could accept your answer too but unfortunately, Stack Overflow only allow us to accept one. and I don't have 15 reputations so far. So, I'm not able to even upvote your answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it does not work because the [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does **not** update the actual string but returns a new string.

> returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end

In my opinion, the easiest way to solve your problem here would be to split the word into characters using the [Array#split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the add the char to each item if the index match the `n` parameters and finally, re-join the array

```js
function three(str, c, n){
  const strAsChar = str.split('')
  
  return strAsChar.map((char, index) => (index - 1) % n === 0 ? 
     char + c :
     char
  ).join('')
}
console.log(three("apple", "c", 2));
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I wish I could accept your answer too but unfortunately, Stack Overflow only allow us to accept one. and I don't have 15 reputations so far. So, I'm not able to even upvote your answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Don't worry ! Welcome to the SO community